# Linq Where Clause Using IN

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having problems with a Linq query that I'm trying to that in SQL would be used as `IN`.  And think in Linq it would be `Contains`. I'll post my code and maybe someone can help me?

```
var claimsearch =
    (from x in dbContext.view_ImageVerification_Shortened
    where x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID.Contains.(2,3,4,5).
    select new
    {
        intImageVerificationID = x.intImageVerificationID,
        intClaimID = x.intClaimID,
        intCurrentCaseStatusLookUpID = x.intCurrentCaseStatusLookUpID,
        vcharCurrentCaseStatusName = x.vcharCurrentCaseStatusName,
        vcharEnergyEmployeeFullName = x.vcharEnergyEmployeeFullName,
        vcharClaimDocsTabHTTPNOCTSLink = x.vcharClaimDocsTabHTTPNOCTSLink,
        intDocumentID = x.intDocumentID,
        vcharDocumentName = x.vcharDocumentName,
        intDocumentTypeID = x.intDocumentTypeID,
        vcharDocumentType = x.vcharDocumentType,
        vcharDocumentFullFileName = x.vcharDocumentFullFileName,
        vcharDocumentHttpFullFileName = x.vcharDocumentHttpFullFileName,
        intContainerID = x.intContainerID,
        vcharContainerDescription = x.vcharContainerDescription,
        intContainerTypeID = x.intContainerTypeID,
        intCurrentImageVerificationTrackingID = x.intCurrentImageVerificationTrackingID,
        intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID = x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID,
        vcharCurrentImageVerificationStatusDescription = x.vcharCurrentImageVerificationStatusDescription,
        intCurrentImageVerificationTrackingUserID = x.intCurrentImageVerificationTrackingUserID,
        dtmCurrentImageVerificationTrackingDate = x.dtmCurrentImageVerificationTrackingDate,
        vcharCurrentImageVerificationTrackingNotes = x.vcharCurrentImageVerificationTrackingNotes,
        vcharCurrentImageVerificationStatusDescriptionUserAndDate = x.vcharCurrentImageVerificationStatusDescriptionUserAndDate,
        intPageCount = x.intPageCount,
        intClaimType = x.intClaimType
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: What are the problems that you're having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
where new[] {(int?) 2,3,4,5}.Contains(x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID)
// cast to int? for nullable
```

This will return true, if your `intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID` is present in the array.

You can extract out the numbers to an array and then use that in your query., like:

```
nt?[] array = new int?[] {2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and then in condition do:

```
where array.Contains(x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID)
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error.  'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>        (System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments C:\_Applications-TFS\IVS\Main\ImageVerificationSystem\ImageVerificationSystem\Admin.aspx.cs 29 42 ImageVerificationSystem

Comment: @hollyquinn, just include `using System.Linq;` in your using directives.

Comment: I am also getting this error

Comment: Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int?>' C:\_Applications-TFS\IVS\Main\ImageVerificationSystem\ImageVerificationSystem\Admin.aspx.cs 29 42 ImageVerificationSystem

Comment: @hollyquinn, just try `var array = new[] {2,3,4,5};` and then in condition `where array.Contains(x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID)`

Comment: @hollyquinn, I think I have fixed it, your field type is nullable, and you need a nullable int `int?` type array. See the updated answer.

Comment: It's still not working I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: @hollyquinn, with `where new[] {(int?) 2,3,4,5}.Contains(x.intCurrentImageVerificationStatusID)` ???